# Unit Testing iOS within Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, tdd

I have an existing application that I'm porting over to iOS. I currently run unit tests with every build. My tests are integrated into my application for simplicity with testing, so when I pass `-t`, my tests run. The very first thing I do in my `main` is this:

```
for(int ii=1;ii<argc;++ii)
{
    if(strcmp("-t", argv[ii]) == 0)
        return RunAllTests(argc, argv);
}
```

This works great on the desktop and I'd love for it to work with iOS too. When I manually run the application in the simulator with the `-t` flag passed, the tests run as expected. Unfortunately it doesn't work when run as a post-build step. I run this script with every build: `$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/$TARGET_NAME -t`. When it runs I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
  Referenced from: /development/test/projects/../bin/test.app/test
  Reason: image not found
/development/test/projects/../obj/test.build/Script-27DEB636151ECEC80003FE53.sh: line 2:  8720 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME.app/$TARGET_NAME -t
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 133
```

I'm assuming thats because the IDE is attempting to run the executable directly rather than in the simulator.

I know iOS has a Unit Testing framework, but I already have a workflow in place and I'd hate to have to rewrite all my tests just to unit test on iOS. Is there a way to force Xcode to run my post-build step in the simulator so my tests run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, on the menu, choose **Product->Edit Scheme...**. I assume you're using Run or maybe Test, but it doesn't matter. Whatever you run with, click on the **Arguments** tab on the right. You'll see *"Arguments Passed On Launch"*. Add your parameter there. That should work.